# Swift MapKit press button to change coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, button, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I want to do like this:

On mapView I have 3 button's. When the app ran first - coordinates initially shows from 1 button.  When usen press Second or another button - coordinates change to another

[image]

```
var lang = 40.7143528
var long = -74.0059731
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.delegate = self

    let distanceSpan: CLLocationDegrees = 2000
    let bsuCSCampus: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lang, long)

    mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(bsuCSCampus, distanceSpan, distanceSpan), animated: true)

    annotation.coordinate = bsuCSCampus
    annotation.title = "Big Ben"
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)


    @IBAction func firstBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    lang = 40.7143528
    long = -74.0059731
}

@IBAction func secondBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    lang = 40.69144874
    long = -73.9290688
}

@IBAction func thirdBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    lang = 40.63728056
    long = -73.9455483
}
```

But when I press any button nothing happens

Comment: What do you want to happen? Do you want the annotation to change to the one you tapped? Do you want the map to re-center on the new location? Both things?

Comment: @DuncanC Both things

Comment: What you do inside viewDidLoad should be done inside every action , plus removing the annotation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest having a function that you use to add annotations and zoom to them:

```
func addAnnotation(lang: Double, long: Double, title: String) {
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

    let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lang, long)

    mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, distanceSpan, distanceSpan), animated: true)

    annotation.coordinate = location
    annotation.title = title
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
}
```

This would make your code look like this:

```
var lang = 40.7143528
var long = -74.0059731
let distanceSpan: CLLocationDegrees = 2000


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.delegate = self
}
```

Tapping the buttons would call this function with the desired `lang`, `long` and the title of the annotation:

```
@IBAction func firstBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    addAnnotation(lang: 40.7143528, long: -74.0059731, title: "Big Ben")
}

@IBAction func secondBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    addAnnotation(lang: 40.69144874, long: -73.9290688, title: "963 Greene Ave, Brooklyn")
}

@IBAction func thirdBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    addAnnotation(lang: 40.63728056, long: -73.9455483, title: "585 E 32nd St, Brooklyn")
}
```

If you have an array of location dictionaries:

```
var locations = [["latitude": 40.7143528, "longitude": -74.0059731],
                 ["latitude": 40.69144874, "longitude": -73.9290688],
                 ["latitude": 40.63728056, "longitude": -73.9455483]]
```

then you could use this function:

```
func addAnnotations(From arrayOfLocations : [[String : Double]]) {
    let annotations: [MKPointAnnotation] = arrayOfLocations.map {locationDictionary in
        guard let latitude = locationDictionary["latitude"], let longitude = locationDictionary["longitude"] else {
            fatalError("Wrong coordinates")
        }
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        return annotation
    }
    mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
    mapView.showAnnotations(annotations, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Ok Thank you. For one annotation it's good, bit if there will be more then one? Create var location = [["latitude": 40.7143528, "longitude": -74.0059731], ["latitude": 40.69144874, "longitude": -73.9290688],["latitude": 40.63728056, "longitude": -73.9455483]] ?

Comment: @Andrew0 updated the answer. If this code helped you don't forget to mark this answer as the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Of course nothing happens. You have 2 instance variables, lat and long, and your IBAction is simply changing those instance variables. They have **nothing** to do with what the map displays.

If you only want one annotation to show at a time, and want to center the map on that annotation each time, you should:

Create a function `showAnnotationAt(coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D)`

In that function:

- remove all annotations
- add an annotation at the specified coordinate
- center the map at that coordinate.

Now call that function from viewDidLoad() and from all of your button actions.

See if you can work out how to code that. If have trouble, post your code and somebody will help you debug it. Do **not** ask me to write that code for you.